# VaR from Bayesian GARCH / Quantile Estimation

Tags: bayesian, stochastic-processes, garch, quantiles, volatility

I have fitted a Bayesian GARCH(1,1) model with Student $t$ innovations to some time series data, $X_1,...,X_n$ and now want to estimate Value-at-Risk (VaR) (i.e., 5% quantiles) at each times $t=1,,...,n$. To do so, I'm using `bayesGARCH` in `R`, which returns an `mcmc` object from which I can obtain samples from the posterior distribution of the coefficients $\theta$, which in turn determine $\textrm{Var}(X_t)$.

More formally, I want to estimate the quantiles of a random variable $X_t$ which is constructed as follows:
$$ X_t = \sigma_t(\theta) Z_t $$
$$ \theta \sim F $$
$$ Z_t \sim \sqrt{\frac{\nu-2}{\nu}} ~ t_\nu, $$
where $F$ is unknown but I have $M$ samples from it. ($t_\nu$ is scaled to that $\textrm{Var}(Z_t) = 1$ and hence $\textrm{Var}(X_t) = \sigma_t^2$.) Given $\theta$, I can readily compute $\sigma_t$.

If $\sigma_t$ were fixed, then clearly $X_t \sim \sigma_t \sqrt{\frac{\nu-2}{\nu}} t_\nu$. The stochasticity of $\sigma_t$ complicates estimating the quantiles of $X_t$.

I was thinking of 2 approaches:

1. For $j=1,...,M$, simulate $X_j \sim \sigma_t(\theta_j) \sqrt{\frac{\nu-2}{\nu}} t_\nu$ (perhaps multiple times). Then, take $\widehat{\textrm{VaR}}$ as the empirical 5% quantile of $X_1,...X_M$.
2. For $j=1,...,M$, let $\widehat{\textrm{VaR}}_j$ be the 5% quantile of $\sigma_t(\theta_j) \sqrt{\frac{\nu-2}{\nu}} t_\nu$. Then, take $\widehat{\textrm{VaR}} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_j \widehat{\textrm{VaR}}_j$.

My question is: which of the two approaches are valid? Does there exist a more appropriate method?

To me, approach (1) seems reasonable, yet perhaps inefficient. Approach (2), might be invalid, but I couldn't say why. Indeed, these two approaches yield quite different results, especially for more extreme quantiles).

Comment: I'm sure someone can answer more rigorously. What follows is just my intuition. What you are aiming to do is to calculate the 5th percentile of the posterior distribution (calculate full distribution under each $\theta_j$, average across j=1:M to get the posterior distribution, then take 5th percentile). Approach (1) is doing that. Approach (2) is not and will provide a biased estimate. Think about a downside outlier value of theta_j. The 5th percentile under this theta_j would be at a much smaller percentile under the posterior, and will pull hat{VaR} down disproportionately under approach 2.